# mobile website programming starter

Tags: mobile, web

I used to be a Flash developer with some knowledge on HTML. I am jumping into the mobile website development now. I really got confused where to start. I did went to Safari web developer resources but it does not seem to be a good place to start. I am essentially looking for a place to start (e.g., book, tutorial website, etc). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mobile website development i think thats the wrong road...(kinda)

you should google up css media types which will change your page on the fly from screen to mobile sizes depending on what you set.

for example

```
@media screen, projection, tv {
  #foo { css here for mobile constraints }
}
```

or declare a seperate mobile stylesheet in the head area...kinda like this

```
<link href="scripts/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 320px)" >

<link href="scripts/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)" >
```

and if your COMPLETELY lost...go to lynda.com and search there..they have alot of decent stuff(some disagree) for begginers.

or go here for begginer stuff http://teamtreehouse.com/

and like always..if you need to SEE it in action, youtube it lol.

good luck